# CloudFormation - ReplicationGroup - Specify the name

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, tags, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

I'm create a CloudFormation template to create Redis in ElastiCache Cluster, everything works fine.
However I'm not able to modify the name of the cluster.

Here is my code:

```
Resources:
Redis:
    Type: 'AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup'
    Properties:

        ReplicationGroupDescription: RedisCluster
        NumCacheClusters: '2'
        Engine: redis
        MultiAZEnabled: yes
        CacheNodeType: cache.t2.micro
        AutomaticFailoverEnabled: 'true'
        CacheSubnetGroupName: !Ref RedisSubnetGroup
        EngineVersion: 5.0.6
        PreferredMaintenanceWindow: mon:03:00-mon:04:00
        Tags: 
            - Key: Cluster Name
              Value: "Redis"
            - Key: Name
              Value: "Redis"
        SecurityGroupIds: 
            - !Ref RedisSecurityGroup
```

It's look like the tags doesn't work in this case.

What is the right way to specify the name for the cluster ?

Comment: Is maybe [ClusterName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html#cfn-elasticache-cachecluster-clustername) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is set using [ReplicationGroupId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html#cfn-elasticache-replicationgroup-replicationgroupid):

> The replication group identifier. This parameter is stored as a lowercase string.

Comment: Your Answer is Right, Thank you